# How to define more generic classes and interface when using realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to write a function that gets a list of games and use a callback to load the results. This is what i have right now:

```
public void getAllGames(OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Game>> callback) {
    realm.where(Game.class).findAllSortedAsync("startTime").addChangeListener(callback);
}
```

I want to make decouple Realm(`OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener` and `RealmResults`) from this function, but I don't know how. I tried creating a listener that extends the `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener` but I am still stuck with the `RealmResults`, and when I try to extend that it said `BaseRealm` is private so it is impossible for me to create a constructor for that. How can I make it look like this:

```
public void getAllGames(SomeListener<SomeList<Game>> callback) {
    realm.where(Game.class).findAllSortedAsync("startTime").addChangeListener(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Derp, all I should have done is write the callback behaviour inside the `getAllGames` function:

```
public void getAllGames(SomeListener<List<Game>> callback) {
    realm.where(Game.class).findAllSortedAsync("startTime").addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Game>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Game> collection, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            callback.callback(collection);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: wrong answer, if your variable returned by `findAllSortedAsync()` gets GCd, the change listener will never be called.

Comment: ok, but if that is the case, no matter how you write the code you can never guarantee that any listener you provided because how can you make sure something never got GC?

Comment: you can [keep it in a thread local strong reference counter and remove it from the ref counter once the query is done](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory.java#L52-L57), but then again I'm a bit concerned about how you're listening for changes that happen to the provided RealmResults after initially calling `getAllGames()`.

Comment: oh so you mean i should keep the `RealmResult` return by `findAllSortedAsync` and add the callback accordingly?

Comment: yep pretty much exactly what I meant